# UserControl not rendering correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, telerik, rendering

I have two UserControls and one View. I have a grid with a button that when clicked, sends an object to the parent (The View) and then uses that object to update a second control. My problem though is that when I debug it, everything is all good but once the page renders again, my Second UserControl is still not visible AND the textbox remains empty.

The First UserControl is called ctrlMyRoster
ascx:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %> 
<telerik:RadGrid ID="radgMyRosters" CssClass="radgMyRosters" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnItemCommand="radgMyRosters_ItemCommand">
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="RosterName" HeaderText="RosterName" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="RosterName">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid-header" HeaderStyle-Width="51px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnEditRoster" runat="server" CssClass="btnGreen" CommandName="Edits" Text="Edit"></asp:Button>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

ctrlMyRoster CodeBehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radgMyRosters.DataSource = lstUsersCurrentRoster;
}

public event EventHandler EditButtonClicked;

private void OnEditButtonClick(int RowSelected)
{
    if (EditButtonClicked != null)
    {
        EditButtonClicked(lstUsersCurrentRoster[RowSelected], EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

protected void radgMyRosters_ItemCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edits")
    {
        OnEditButtonClick(e.Item.ItemIndex);
    }
}
```

The Second UserControl ctrlRosterDetail ascx

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"> Name: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtRosterName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

ctrlRosterDetail CodeBehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Empty
}
```

ViewMyRoster ascx:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<%@ Register Src="UserControls/ctrlMyRosters.ascx" TagName="ctrlMyRosters" TagPrefix="MyControls" %>
<%@ Register Src="UserControls/ctrlRosterDetails.ascx" TagName="ctrlrosterdetails" TagPrefix="MyControls" %>
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" ID="rapCreateWindowContainer" LoadingPanelID="ralpLoadingPanel"> 
    <aau:ctrlMyRosters ID="ctrlMyRosters1" runat="server" />
    <aau:ctrlrosterdetails ID="ctrlRosterDetails1" runat="server" Visible="False" />
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

ViewMyRoster CodeBehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctrlMyRosters1.EditButtonClicked += new EventHandler(ctrlMyRosters1_EditButtonClicked);
}

private void ctrlMyRosters1_EditButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)ctrlRosterDetails1.Controls[0]).Text = ((EventRoster)sender).Name;
    ctrlRosterDetails1.Visible = true;
}
```

Am I missing something? Maybe it's something to do with the .Net page lifecycle?

Maybe I should use a different approach? All I want to do is pass information from the first UserControl to the second UserControl.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "once the page renders again"?

Comment: @DanM I mean after the postback is done